# domain and cookies issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies, dns

I have a website with members area. The login built with cookies.

The problem is that the browser reffering `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` as diffrent sites.

I can be logged into my user at `domain.com`, but if I enter `www.domain.com` I won't be logged in.
I can even be logged in two diffrent users at once, one at `domain.com` and the other at `www.domain.com`.

How can I fix it and make browsers reffer the domain same way with or without `www`?

Thank you!

EDIT:
That's the code part which creating the cookies:

```
setcookie('id',$s_u['ID']);
setcookie('pe',$s_u['password']);
```

Comment: Can u post the logic you used ?

Comment: I edited the question. that's what you meant?

Comment: are you setting the password in cookies without encryption ?

Comment: no. `$s_u['password']` is encrypted with md5.

Comment: @OfirH and are you routing all the traffic to **www** subdomain OR we can access your website in both the form ? ( with www AND without www)

Comment: you can accses both ways. But I got answer for my question. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
  $hour =time()+3600*24; // 1 day
  setcookie("ID", $id, $hour,"/", ".sitename.com"); 
  setcookie("Key", $key, $hour,"/", ".sitename.com");
```

Comment: Thanks! That fix the problem. But it dosen't work if I set cookie that expires when the browser is closed. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can omit expire time, then It ll expire when browser closed